# Creating a Boolean function that determines if two arrays are shift equivalent

Tags: c++, function, boolean, dynamic-arrays, boolean-expression

Two arrays:

```
a[] = {1 2 3 4}
b[] = {3 4 1 2}
```

The bottom array is simply the top array shifted to the right two places. If the top array can be right shifted to create the bottom array, we call them shift equivalent.

Here is my attempt at creating a function (I need to use a Boolean function) to determine if two arrays are "shift equivalent":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int size) {

    int value; // if 1 returns as truth
    int k; // counter to compare both arrays

    for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + j];
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k <= size; k++) {
        if (a[k] != b[k]) {
            value = 0;
        } else value = 1;
    }

    return (value == 1);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Please input a size " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int *mtrx = new int[n];
    int *mtrx1 = new int[n];
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        cout << "Please make entries for the first array: " << endl;
        cin >> mtrx[x];
    }
    x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        cout << "Please make entries for the 2nd array: " << endl;
        cin >> mtrx1[x];
    }

    bool answr = equivalent(mtrx, mtrx1, n = n - 1);

    if (answr) {
        cout << "They are shift equivalent." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "They are not shift equivalent." << endl;
    }

    delete[] mtrx;
    delete[] mtrx1;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute my program, I use `array1 = {1 2 3}` and `array2 = {3 1 2}` to test shift equivalency. They are supposed to be, but my program says they aren't.

Comment: your brace style is (was) very weird.

Comment: I find editing for spaces even weirder.

Comment: what is a brace style? I am sorry I am new to programming.

Comment: Your logic also makes no sense..

Comment: As for brace style, do you notice how after @Rapptz's edit, all the `{` start after the expression, and the `}` appears on the begining of its own line? This is pretty much the most common style, and shows clearly where the blocks end. Your style had the `}` appear on the end of the last statement which is quite confusing and unobvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem which I see in your code is that you access memory beyond the array. If you add two indices, you have to make sure that they "wrap around" if you want to treat your array cyclic. This can be done with a modulo. Instead of

```
a[i + j]
```

you should write

```
a[(i + j) % size]
```

I'd split your algorithm into two parts: First, write a function which tests if `a` equals `b` with a shift of `shift`. Then, within a second function (the final `equivalent` function), test for all possible values for `shift`.

```
bool equivalentFixed(int a[], int b[], int size, int shift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != a[(i + shift) % size])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int size) {
    for (int shift = 0; shift < size; ++shift) {
        if (equivalentFixed(a, b, size, shift))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you look close, you don't see any local variable to hold (store) the value if the arrays are equivalent. Indeed, your code has a problem here, too, since you always overwrite the old status with the new one for each single entry you compare. So if the comparison fails anywhere during scanning the arrays, but the very last entry compares to equal, you return "yes, they are equal", since you have overwritten the status.

Now have a look at my `equivalent` implementation. I scan for different offsets (`shift`) if the arrays compare equal. Let's focus on this function, not how the comparison is done in the other function. The point is: We have to return true if for *any* shift they compare equal, not for *the last* one and not for *all*.

The idea to solve this is to break the loop (stop) if you found a solution. You can even return the whole function, since you know the complete return value, namely `true`.

If for no possible shift the comparison is true, we didn't find any possible shift, so they aren't "shift equivalent".

I used a very similar approach to implement the comparison of two arrays with a fixed shift (`equivalentFixed`). Can you explain how this is done?

Comment: shift of shift? Do you mean I should make a function named shift?

Comment: Also, why would you break them into two functions? I am curious.

Comment: @paddy Show me a better one. Also, this is about learning trivial code, not about algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @Chase Please see my edit. I tried my best to explain why I did this. It makes the code cleaner.

Comment: @Chase Regarding the "shift of shift": I meant a fixed shift. I give it a name, which is `shift`. Sorry, I didn't want to confuse you here. ;)

Comment: @Chase You're absolutely right. It only makes sense in combination with the second function: This one tests for *all possible shifts* (from 0 to size-1) and tests if the arrays are shift-equivalent with *that fixed* shift. Do you understand?

Comment: When you wrote this:                                                           if (a[i] != a[(i + shift) % size])
           return false;                                                   Does that mean I am supposed to input a value for shift in the int main()?

Comment: I'm also new to stack overflow, so please excuse me if I seem like I'm posting the same question twice. I don't know how to edit, so when I see "delete" I clicked that and I do not know if my deleted comment is still visible to anyone else.

Comment: No, that's a function parameter. It's passed from `equivalent` towards the call of `equivalentFixed`. The value changes for each call, so we try different shifts (which is what we need).

Comment: An "edit" link should be just next to the red "X" which you use to delete the comment. If it isn't, this is maybe you have not enough reputation score yet. If you delete a comment, it's deleted for everybody.

Comment: @Chase Did my answer solve your problem? If so, you should click on the tick symbol just below the vote arrows of this answer to "accept the answer". This will give both you and me reputation score. (Of course, if there is another answer which answers the question better, feel free to accept that.)

Answer (score 0):

here you get `i+j>size`

```
a[i]=a[i+j];
```

And here just a litte variation to make the whole in only one function: (this is a rare case when it is good to use a dynosaur goto - to get out of an internal loop, whithout introducing new temporal variables)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int size) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] != b[(i + j)%size]) goto next_shift;
        }
        return true;
        next_shift: ;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Please input a size " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int *mtrx = new int[n];
    int *mtrx1 = new int[n];
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        cout << "Please make entries for the first array: " << endl;
        cin >> mtrx[x];
    }
    x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        cout << "Please make entries for the 2nd array: " << endl;
        cin >> mtrx1[x];
    }

    bool answr = equivalent(mtrx, mtrx1, n );

    if (answr) {
        cout << "They are shift equivalent." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "They are not shift equivalent." << endl;
    }

    delete[] mtrx;
    delete[] mtrx1;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** From:The C+ + Programming Language. Third Edition. Bjarne Stroustrup

> **6.3.4 Goto [expr.goto]** 
>   C++ possesses the infamous g o t o :

```
goto identifier ;
identifier : statement
```

> The g o t o has few uses in general highlevel programming

…

> One of the few sensible uses of `goto` in ordinary code is to break
>   out from a nested loop or switch statement (a `break` breaks out of
>   only the innermost enclosing loop or switchstatement).
>
> For example:

```
voidf ()
{
int i ;
int j ;
for (i = 0 ; i <n ; i ++)
for (j = 0 ; j <m ; j ++) i f (nm [i ][j ] == a ) goto found ;
// not found
// ...
found :
// nm[i][j] == a
}
```

Comment: @leemes yes, serious :-) . See EDIT.